# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'エラーが出る

Tags: python, 画像処理

画像の輪郭を読み取るコードを書いているのですが、`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'`というエラーが出てきてしまいます。いろいろ調べてみて`tuple([])`を使ってみてエラーを直しているサイトを見つけて試してみたのですが、治らず、ほかにもいろいろ試してみたのですが結局治らずでここに質問させていただきます

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
img = plt.imread('data/capital_e.png')
plt.imshow(img)
verical_filter =[[-1,-2,1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]]
horizaontal_filter = [[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]
n = img.shape
m = img.shape
d = img.shape
vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img)
for row in range(3, n-2):
    for col in range(3, m-2):
        local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,0]
        transformed_pixels = verical_filter * local_pixels
        vertical_score = (transformed_pixels.sum() + 4)/8
        vertical_edges_img =[row,col] = [vertical_score] * 3
```

エラーメッセージ

```
 1 vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img)
----> 2 for row in range(3, n-2):
      3     for col in range(3, m-2):
      4         local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,0]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: `n = img.shape` としていますので、当該のエラーが発生しています。これは `m = img.shape` と `d = img.shape` も同様です。おそらく、`n, m, d = img.shape` とするのだと思います。

Comment: もしも元となるソースコードが存在するのなら, そのサイト記したほうがよいかも(あるいは書籍名)

Comment: metropolisさんのコメントで解決すると思いますが、oririさんコメントのようにそもそもの元にした書籍/記事/サイト等があれば、更に対策のために参考にした記事/サイトと共に質問記事に紹介リンク等を追記してみてください。あと可能ならば使っている画像データも記事にアップロードするか、そうでなければ何処から入手出来るか方法や紹介リンクを貼ってみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Answer (score 1):

エラーの内容

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

> `-` の被演算子 (operand) として，`tuple` と `int` はサポートされてないよ

といっています．場所は `range(3, n-2)` のところなので，`n` が意図せず `tuple` になってるのでは

→`n` の定義は

```
n = img.shape
```

この `img` は

```
img = plt.imread('data/capital_e.png')
```

なので，[`plt.imread`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) が返す [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array)（このコードでは `img`） の [`shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy-ndarray-shape) に対して引き算をしようとしているのでエラーが出ています．たとえば　`(2,3,4) - 1` がエラーになるのは直感的ですよね．

[@metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/47127/metropolis) さんのコメント通り，もとの意図は `n, m, d = img.shape` だったのでしょう．