# ファンクションがエラーは出ないのにうまく動かない

Tags: python, 画像処理

vertical filterという名前のファンクション作り、それを使い画像の縦の部分を検知し横の部分との識別をし、白と黒に分けて新たな画像を作るというものを作っています。
ファンクションにする前のコードでは自分が思うような画像を出すことができるのですが、ファンクションに書き換えるとうまく動きません。自分の書き直し方が違うというのは分かっているのですが、どう書き直せばいいのか分からなかったのでこちらで質問させていただきました。以下に元のコードとそこから出来上がった画像。ファンクションに書き直した時のコードとそこからできた画像を張っているのでご確認お願い致します。白黒の画像が自分が求めている結果で、カラーの方がオリジナルの画像でありファンクションを通した結果の画像です

元のコード

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
!pip install scikit-image

verical_filter =[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]]
#with vertical filter
vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img) #it is going to be initially all zeros
for row in range(3, n-2): #loop every single pixels
    for col in range(3, m-2):
        local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,1] 
        transformed_pixels = verical_filter * local_pixels
        vertical_score = (transformed_pixels.sum() +4)/8 
       
    vertical_edges_img[row, col] = [vertical_score] * 3




plt.imshow(vertical_edges_img)
```

[image: vertical filterを使った後の画像]

書き直し後のコードimportの部分は省略

```
def vertical_img(img):
verical_filter =[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]] 
vertical_edges_img = np.zeros_like(img) 
upsidedown_pic = np.array(img)
for row in range(3, n-2): #loop every single pixels
    for col in range(3, m-2):
        local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2,col-1:col+2,1] 
        transformed_pixels = verical_filter * local_pixels
        vertical_score = (transformed_pixels.sum() +4)/8 
        vertical_edges_img[row, col] = [vertical_score] * 3

return upsidedown_pic


vert_img = vertical_img(img)
plt.imshow(vert_img)
```

[image: ファンクションを通した後の画像（オリジナルの画像と一緒）]

Comment: 残念ながら提示されたソースコードは、両方とも質問記事を書く際に削りすぎたか何かしてimgという変数(読み込んだ画像データ？)が未定義でエラーになりますし、2つ目のソースコードは質問時の転記/編集ミスでしょうか、関数内の処理がインデントされておらずエラーになります。変数imgの方は例えば動作させている環境がgoogle colabやjupyter lab/notebookで、以前に別のセル等で行われた処理の残滓かもしれませんね。あるいは[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/96201/26370)の続きと言うことでしょうか？ こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に記事内容を見直してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

ソースコードが適切なものになったとして、書き直し版で加わった処理は初期化した`upsidedown_pic = np.array(img)`を何もしないで戻り値にしています。`return upsidedown_pic`

書き直しが単なる関数化を目的としたものであるなら、`upsidedown_pic`関連の処理は削除して戻り値を`return vertical_edges_img`とするだけで良いのでは？

あるいは`upsidedown_pic`という名前からして、何かしら追加の処理を行うつもりなら、`return upsidedown_pic`の前に`vertical_edges_img`から`upsidedown_pic`に変換なり加工なりする処理を入れる必要があるでしょう。